# Linked List making segmentation fault

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault

Below I have made a simple Linked List in C. The code is currently producing a segmentation fault which I find odd because I was copying an example from our current book. The only thing I did to the code was put the code into the method "addToList". I'm aware the segmentation fault is coming from the method addToList but I do not know where I made a mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct node {
  int val;
  struct node *next;
} Node;

void addToList(Node *, int);
void printList(Node *);

void main() {
  int x;
  Node *head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  for (x = 1; x < 4); x++) {
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    x = scanf("%d");
    addToList(head, x);
  }
  printList(head);
}

void addToList(Node *head, int val) {
  Node *current = head;

  while (current->next != NULL) {
    current = current->next;
  }

  current->next = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  current->next->val = val;
  current->next->next = NULL;
}

void printList(Node *head) {
  Node *current = head;

  while (current != NULL) {
    printf("%d->", current->val);
    current = current->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Any help with telling me what is wrong or where I'm making the mistake would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the posted code does not compile (well, maybe it would under Visual Studio as that tool has a LOT of problems built it.)  To start, there are only 2 valid signatures for the `main()` function: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  I.E. the return type is always `int`, not `void`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: ( malloc, calloc, realloc ), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: `head` is not initialized in `main`. `head->next` is pointing into the nirvana, so there is now way to tell how often the `while` loop in `addToList` is going to loop until you get segfault.

Comment: I'm using debian on Linux. Using void for the type for main lets the code compile.

Comment: regarding: `x = scanf("%d");` 1) when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) the value in `x` could be 0 or 1 or EOF.  I.E. Your understanding of the syntax of the function is not correct.  Suggest: `if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &x ) ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed to read a value for x\n" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: I'm using `ubuntu (debian) Linux`  the compiler will output a warning message if the return type from `main()` is NOT `int`

Comment: regarding: `Node *head = malloc(sizeof(Node));`  The line misrepresents what the `addToList()` function should be looking for.  Suggest: `Node *head = NULL;`   Then the first parameter to `addToList()` should be the address of `head`  I.E.  `addToList( &head, x );` and the prototype for `addToList()` should be similar to: `void addToList( Node **head, int val )`

Comment: the function: `addToList()` should be checking if `*head` is NULL.  if NULL, then assign the new node similar to `*head = current;`  otherwise, search for the last entry in the chain and then `*current-next = newnode;`

Comment: this is nonsense: `while (current = current->next != NULL) {
    current = current->next;`   Suggest: `while( current->next ) { current = current-next; }`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: learn to use valgrind

Comment: regarding: `printf("%d->", current->val);`  this will result in: `1->2->3->` etc.  suggest inserting a space between the values and checking for when the last value is about to be output and not outputting the `->`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look carefully at your code:

```
int main(void) {
  int x;
  Node *head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  for (x = 1; x < 4); x++) {
      ...
    addToList(head, x);
  }
  ...
}
```

You are not initializing the memory, so `head->val` and `head->next` are not
initialized. Because of that

```
while (current->next != NULL) {
    current = current->next;
}
```

will loop an undefined amount of times. The first `current->next` is most
probably not `NULL`, so `current = current->next` get executed. At that point `current` is pointing to nowhere, hence the undefined behaviour which in your case leads to a segfault.

You have to initialized the memory like this:

```
Node *head = malloc(sizeof *head);
if(head == NULL)
    // error handling

head->next = NULL;
```

But you could also use `calloc`, which also sets the memory to 0, thus you don't have to initialize the values (in this case):

```
Node *head = calloc(1, sizeof *head);
if(head == NULL)
    // error handling
```

You should always check for the return value of `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`.

Also note that the signature of the `main` function can be one of these:

- `int main(void);`
- `int main(int argc, char **argv);`
- `int main(int argc, char *argv[]);`

**edit**

Another error I've noticed right now:

```
x = scanf("%d");
```

That's not how [`scanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) works. You have to pass a pointer, `scanf` saves the
scanned value through the passed pointer. `scanf` returns the number of matched
values on success, in this case, success would be 1:

```
int num;
int ret = scanf("%d", &num);
if(ret != 1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not read value from the user\n");
    continue; // to contiune looping

    // you could also do a break; and stop the looping, or
    // exit(1), etc.
}
    // error with scanf
```

Also don't use the same variable `x` for the loop iteration and user input,
otherwise you are messing with the loop.

**edit**

> *User user3629249 wrote in the comment*
>
> good information, however the result will be the first entry in the linked list will contain garbage.
>   Better to declare head via: `Node *head = NULL`; and the function `addToList()` check for NULL and proceed accordingly.

That's right, the `head` element doesn't save any number in this way.

**Option 1: double pointer**

Here `addToList` receives a double pointer. The initialization of `head` occurs
when `*head` points to `NULL`. The function allocates memory for it, initializes
the memory, saves the value and returns. In the concurrent calls of `addToList`
`*head` won't be `NULL`, so `addToList` looks for the end of the list.

I've made small changes in the way you do `malloc` and `realloc`. Also I added
an implementation of `freeList` which should be used to free the memory:

```
void addToList(Node **head, int val) {
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "head cannot be NULL\n");
        return;
    }


    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = calloc(1, sizeof **head);
        head[0]->val = val;
        head[0]->next = NULL;
        return;
    }
    Node *current = *head;

    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }

    current->next = malloc(sizeof *current->next);
    if(current->next == NULL)
        return;
    current->next->val = val;
    current->next->next = NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    Node *head = NULL;
    for (x = 1; x < 4; x++)
    {
        int val;
        printf("Enter an integer: ");
        if(scanf("%d", &val) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not read from user. Skipping entry\n");
            continue;
        }

        addToList(&head, val);
    }

    printList(head);

    freeList(head);
    return 0;
}

void freeList(Node *head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
        return;

    Node *current = head;
    Node *next;

    while(next = current->next)
    {
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }

    free(current); // the last one

    free(head);
}
```

**Option 2: `addToList` returns a pointer to the head**

Here `addToList` takes a pointer to the head. If it's `NULL`, it allocates
memory and initializes like in the shown above. If `head` is not `NULL`, the
functions looks for the last element and the returns the `head`. On error the
function returns `NULL`.

```
Node *addToList(Node *head, int val) {

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = calloc(1, sizeof **head);
        head->val = val;
        head->next = NULL;
        return head;
    }
    Node *current = *head;

    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }

    current->next = malloc(sizeof *current->next);
    if(current->next == NULL)
        return NULL;
    current->next->val = val;
    current->next->next = NULL;

    return head;
}

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    Node *head = NULL, *tmp;
    for (x = 1; x < 4; x++)
    {
        int val;
        printf("Enter an integer: ");
        if(scanf("%d", &val) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not read from user. Skipping entry\n");
            continue;
        }

        tmp = addToList(head, val);
        if(tmp == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory\n");
            freeList(head);
            return 1;
        }

        head = tmp;

    }

    printList(head);

    freeList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: good information, however the result will be the first entry in the linked list will contain garbage.  Better to declare `head` via: `Node *head = NULL;` and the function `addToList()` check for NULL and proceed accordingly.

Comment: @user3629249 yes I thought about that, unless you don't want to save any number in the head. I'll fix my answer to address this issue.